# Under what conditions do auto-turrets stay in play?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

The bonus pickups provide a number of auto-turrets, both for personal and for vehicles, as well as droids that can fire in a similar manner.

That left me wondering how long they last once I'm killed, will they disappear after a period of time.  Obviously ending the level will wipe them from the level.

Is it possible to have multiple turrets? of the same type?

Do auto-turrets last until destroyed, or the level ends?

Comment: Your effectivley asking a couple of questions, here. They all come under the umbrella of conditions for staying in play, though, so there shouldnt be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just put a few of these questions to the test.

You cannot have multiple turrets of the same type. I dropped a Viper Probe Droid, picked up another one and dropped the second Viper Probe Droid as well, and the first droid blew up as soon as I dropped the second.

Your turret will stay alive as long as you are alive or until it gets killed - The turret, after you die, has a limited time it will stay alive before it just blows up. Respawning does not seem to affect this timer - I've respawned to see my turret still activated and working before randomly blowing up.

Answer (score 2):

Turrets placed by you remain there until the end of the match, or they are destroyed. I've placed several manned and auto turrets on a particular map, and have died several times, noting that they are still there afterward.

You can have as many turrets (of the same type) as you want. You only need to pick up the powerup that grants them, and place them in valid locations. Note that they are favored targets by enemies. (I've had them destroyed seconds after placing them, most players know how powerful they can be.)

Comment: Most of these are true. I can confirm they persist through death and that you can have multiples of a single or multiple types deployed at once. But I have also seen turrets explode on their own for no obvious reason. So there must be some kind of limitation. Perhaps a time limit too? Not sure...

Comment: @Mufasa I've not experienced that, and my first assumption would be that it was hit with a blaster shot or some kind of grenade/etc., but of course I don't know that for sure. I have had turrets stay extremely long - i.e. place them at the beginning of the round, in maybe a not-great location, and they remain there for the entire match. (Of course maybe the match length wasn't long enough to trigger such an implosion, but again, who knows.)

Comment: [Zephkiel on the battlefront forum said](http://starwars.ea.com/starwars/battlefront/forums/discussion/comment/88699): "They disappear when you respawn, so you can still have them defend a critical point by choosing not to respawn for a few seconds.". I guess this is the opposite of what you've seen.

Comment: There're a lot of statements contradicting this answer on the forum thread @MarkRogers linked. As a new Battlefront player, I don't know what to believe.

Comment: I've seen them still alive even after a round ends, for example in Hero vs Villain mode I've placed an auto turret down as a trooper, and then next round was Darth Vader and still saw my turret there (it was a secluded area of the map)

Comment: That's been my experience as well. Secluded areas.